# using Automapper, Type.GetType in Profile always return null

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Using Automapper, Type.GetType always return null in profile.

Here is my profile:

```
    public NotificationProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.Discriminator,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => Type.GetType(src.EntityType).Name)
            );
     }
```

In debug, In immediate windows, It works when I do:

```
Type.GetType("MyProject.Api.Controllers.Samples.Dtos.SampleDetailsDto").Name =>SampleDetailsDto`
```

But the property value of Discriminator is always Null here:

```
Mapper.Map<GroupedResult<Notification>, GroupedResult<NotificationDto, Guid?>>(result)
```

Is there a way to use "*Type.GetType*" in Profile binding?

Thanks

ps: I opened an issue on github too (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2890)